# Writing a program from our Java textbook as an exercise. I have it exactly as the book has it, but it keeps giving me "Cannot find symbol errors"

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, javac, cannot-find-symbol

I am writing a program out from my Java textbook as practice for writing our own similar program. I have it written exactly as it appears in our book (*Starting Out With Java, From Control Structures Through Data Structures, 3rd Edition, Page 833*) (quadruple checked!) and every time, it throws 8 "cannot find symbol" errors on the same lines, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 *  The OrderCalculatorGUI class creates the GUI for the Brandi's Bagel House application
 */

public class OrderCalculatorGUI extends JFrame
{
    private BagelPanel bagels;
    private ToppingPanel toppings;
    private CofeePanel coffee;
    private GreetingPanel banner;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JButton calcButton;
    private JButton exitButton;
    private final double TAX_RATE = 0.06;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */

    public OrderCalculatorGUI()
    {
        //Display a title.
        setTitle("Order Calculator");

        //Specify an action for the close button.
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //create a orderLayout manager.
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        // Create the custom panels.
        banner = new GreetingPanel();
        bagels = new BagelPanel();
        toppings = new ToppingPanel();
        coffee = new CoffeePanel();

        // Create the button panel.
        buildButtonPanel();

        //Add the components to the content pane.
        add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(bagels, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(toppings, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(coffee, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Pack the contents of the window and display it.
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * The buildButtonPanel method builds the button panel.
     */

    private void buildButtonPanel()
    {
        //Create a panel for the buttons.
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        //Create the buttons.
        calcButton = new JButton("Calculate");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        //Register the action listeners.
        calcButton.addActionListener(new CalcButtonListener());
        exitButton.addActionListener(new ExitButtonListener());

        //Add the buttons to the button panel.
        buttonPanel.add(calcButton);
        buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
    }

    /**
     * Private inner class that handles the event when
     * the user clicks the Calculate button.
     */

    private class CalcButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // Variables to hold the subtotal, tax, and total
            double subtotal, tax, total;

            //Calculate the subtotal.
            subtotal = bagels.getBagelCost() +
                       toppings.getToppingCost() +
                       coffee.getCoffeeCost();

            //Calculate the sales tax.
            tax = subtotal * TAX_RATE;

            //Calculate the total.
            total = subtotal * TAX_RATE;

            //Calculate the total.
            total = subtotal + tax;

            //Display the charges.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                String.format("Subtotal: $%,.2f\n" +
                             "Tax: $%,.2f\n" +
                             "Total: $%,.2f",
                             subtotal, tax, total));   
        }

    }

    /**
     * Private inner class that handles the event when
     * the user clicks the Exit button.
     */

    private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * main method
     */

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new OrderCalculatorGUI();
    }
}
```

And here is the console output in the cmd prompt after running "javac OrderCalculatorGUI.java"

```
OrderCalculatorGUI.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    private BagelPanel bagels;
            ^
  symbol:   class BagelPanel
  location: class OrderCalculatorGUI
OrderCalculatorGUI.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    private ToppingPanel toppings;
            ^
  symbol:   class ToppingPanel
  location: class OrderCalculatorGUI
OrderCalculatorGUI.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    private CofeePanel coffee;
            ^
  symbol:   class CofeePanel
  location: class OrderCalculatorGUI
OrderCalculatorGUI.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    private GreetingPanel banner;
            ^
  symbol:   class GreetingPanel
  location: class OrderCalculatorGUI
OrderCalculatorGUI.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
        banner = new GreetingPanel();
                     ^
  symbol:   class GreetingPanel
  location: class OrderCalculatorGUI
OrderCalculatorGUI.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        bagels = new BagelPanel();
                     ^
  symbol:   class BagelPanel
  location: class OrderCalculatorGUI
OrderCalculatorGUI.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        toppings = new ToppingPanel();
                       ^
  symbol:   class ToppingPanel
  location: class OrderCalculatorGUI
OrderCalculatorGUI.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        coffee = new CoffeePanel();
                     ^
  symbol:   class CoffeePanel
  location: class OrderCalculatorGUI
8 errors
```

At this point I am a bit stumped. I am not sure what went wrong, what silly mistake I'm making, or other weird anomaly is happening. I appreciate any assitance.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are missing the code for `BagelPanel`

Comment: You should have a file in the same directory called BagelPanel that defines your BagelPanel class. Same for the other missing classes. Review your course materials.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error, it says that it is unable to find the symbol that means you have not defined the class Bangel panel, Greeting panel, etc. so in order to use this, you must first define these classes or import the respective package.
**I suggest you to please review your course material and find the suitable code then try again or if you are unable to find then attach the picture of the book`s code here.**
Thank you, Hope this will help you. Happy coding/

Comment: Thank you for the response and sorry for the late reply. As I confirmed in response to the other commenters, the issue was indeed that I had forgotten to write the code for the other classes, and I must have been having severe writers block (or whatever the equivalent coding term is) as to why those errors were there. The book did have the code for the rest of those classes a few pages back. After writing the code I successfully was able to get the program running, and I now feel I have enough of an understanding of it to write my real program assignment. Thank you very much!